# Scale a node's width to adjust to the text while keeping a max-width

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

My problem actually *seems* simple, so apologies if this has been answered before, I wasn't able to find it. Maybe I had the wrong keywords as well.

Current Situation:

```
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=15em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=5em]
```

Here text width has been upped to 15em, because previously the nodes were wrapping the text so fast, that the graph didn't fit on one page and the elements started overlapping.

In my use-case I want to have three vertical graphs next to each other, so it's important to also have tikz honor the maximum-width directive.
I can't use `text width=15em` (or `0.3\textwidth`) as is, because when the text is short, the node itself still remains in it's width.

So essentially I want a node that: If below maximum-width does resize according to the text length, otherwise it shall start wrapping the text.
Also, if possible without too much effort, allow setting that width, like so:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto, maximum-width=0.3\textwidth]
...
```

or similar, but preferrably not in the style definition and not in every individual \node.

Thanks in advance for every help :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please include a complete, compilable minimal working example to make it easier for people to help you.  Oftentimes, that will even solve your problem on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a simple key that does that but there is something somewhat close to this. This answer defines a style `max width node`, which takes arguments of the form `max width node={[<style>]{content}}`, with examples in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{max width node/.style args={[#1]#2}{insert path={
node[#1,opacity=0,overlay](tst){#2}
let \p1=($(tst.east)-(tst.west)$),
    \n1={ifthenelse(\x1>\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/max width},1,0)}
in
\ifdim\n1>0pt
  node[#1,text width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/max width}-4pt]{#2}
\else
  node[#1]{#2}
\fi
}},max width/.initial=5em}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=5em}]
 \path (0,0) [max width node={[block]{pft}}]
  (0,-5) [max width node={[block]{pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft
  pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft 
  pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft}}];
 \path (5,0) [max width node={[block,max width=7em]{pft}}]
  (5,-5) [max width node={[block,max width=7em]{pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft
  pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft 
  pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, and usually minimal working examples are expected to come with questions.